# Electrum Error Message "22"

Tags: address, electrum, error

When I try to send BTC from my Electrum wallet address to one of my unused addresses in Electrum, just as a test, it comes up with an error message `(U'message':u'TX rejected, U'code':-22)`.
I'm using electrum-1.6.2 Install version on my Windows 7 64-bit PC.

I changed the Electrum server and then the transmission worked, so I guess it was an error transmitting data to the server.

Can someone confirm that Error "22" refers to a transmission error to the server?
Also, is there a list of error message numbers, so in future I can refer to the list?

Answer (score 1):

I've been reading the source code of Electrum, and it turns out that the reason why you can't find anything about this is that it's not an Electrum error-it's an error generated by the Bitcoin client, and Electrum is just passing it along.

Now, what causes the error?

There are a bunch of ways it can happen (like trying to send a coinbase transaction), but the number one way that this can happen is if you send the same transaction twice. Unfortunatly, the current implementation of `sendrawtransaction` doesn't really give you any information about why.

(For those that are interested, the relevant error is on [line 555 of rpcrawtransaction.cpp](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/rpcrawtransaction.cpp#L555).

Comment: Thanks for interesting reply, but although I see "TX rejected" on Line 555, I can't find a reference to "code:-22". Is there a list somewhere of error messages, including "22"?

Comment: That's what the constant `RPC_DESERIALIZATION_ERROR` comes out to. PS: You're looking for -22, not 22.

Comment: @user3352 the codes are in https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/bitcoinrpc.h