# Electrum wallet - Can not send bitcoins

Tags: electrum

Does anybody know what this code means?  error: `{u'message': u'64: dust', u'code': -26}`   I've managed to send bitcoins once, same settings, but it only worked once.
Any help is welcome, thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that the amount you were trying to send is below 5430 satoshi? That would be considered [dust](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/10987/5406), and perhaps electrum would not send a transaction with dust. You might need to add more information for us to give you a better answer.

Comment: I think that was the problem, i have send a higher amount and it worked. The "dust" i was trying to send was to test my wallet since i am new in this bitcoin revolution. Thank you very much for this fast reply and the solution! Best regards!

Comment: Cool, glad I could help. I had been researching meanwhile and found a little more about your error. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

According to [another question about an Electrum error message](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/8405/5406) the error message is just passed along by Electrum and originally was generated in BitcoinQt:

According to [rpcprotocol.h](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/rpcprotocol.h) in the source code `error -26` has the following meaning:

```
 RPC_VERIFY_REJECTED = -26, //! Transaction or block was rejected by network rules
```

Guessing from the word "dust" appearing in the message, was the amount you were trying to send below 5430 satoshi? That would be considered [dust](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/10987/5406), and perhaps electrum would not send a transaction with dust.